# Build JFreeChart ant file "build-fx.xml"

Tags: java, xml, ant

I am trying to import `import org.jfree.chart.fx.ChartViewer;` in my program. After some research, I found I needed to build the `build-fx.xml` file to get this package included in my JFreeChart jar. So I used the line of code in a terminal setup to build ant `ant -buildfile build-fx.xml` but I got an error shown in the output below. Am I doing something wrong?

```
C:\Users\dan\Desktop\jfreechart-1.0.19\ant>ant -buildfile build-fx.xml
Buildfile: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\jfreechart-1.0.19\ant\build-fx.xml

initialise:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\jfreechart-1.0.19\build
    [javac] Compiling 629 source files to C:\Users\danie\Desktop\jfreechart-1.0.19\build
    [javac] C:\Users\danie\Desktop\jfreechart-1.0.19\source\org\jfree\chart\fx\ChartViewer.java:122: error: getUserAgentStylesheet() in ChartViewer cannot override getUserAgentStylesheet() in Region
    [javac]     protected String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\dan\Desktop\jfreechart-1.0.19\ant\build-fx.xml:62: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 6 seconds
```

Sorry if this is obvious, it is the first time I have had to build a jar with ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known error and it is fairly simple to fix. See [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117471#p179419)

To fix this problem change `protected String getUserAgentStylesheet() {` to `public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {` in the source files and then run the ant build again.

This should successfully build a jar called `jfreechart-1.0.19-fx.jar` to the lib folder